# Sliding in content on hover over #viewer with .load and sliding away when hovering over #button2 or #button3

Tags: php, jquery

I have this jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#display').hover(
  function () {
$('#viewer').load('display.php');
});
});
```

What I want to happen is, for the content to slide in when hovering over #viewer and I want it to slide away when it hovers over #button1 or #button2 (so basically div#viewer slides away)

Comment: what is the problem you are having with this code? is it loading the content in the source but not visible in the browser? or is it failing to load in the text from the source?

Comment: no it loads ...but its instant and then it stays there

Comment: I wanted more of a slide in/out effect

Comment: I will post a version in the answer that should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#viewer').height(0);
    $('#display').hover(
        function () {
            $('#viewer').load('display.php');
            $('#viewer').animate({height:'100'});
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: hmmmm doesn't seem to be loading it now

Comment: sorry, didn't test the code before sending, it should work now.